# javascript append to text file ignoring element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script pieced together from a few sources

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-

git.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#TextToSave").text() == "type your text here ...") {
   $("#TextToSave").text($(this).html());
    } else {
        $("#TextToSave").text($("#TextToSave").text() + $(this).html());
    }
});

});//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="button">
<track><location>path 1</location></track></a><br>

<a href="#" class="button">
<track><location>path 2</location></track></a><br>

<a href="#" class="button">
<track><location>path 3</location></track></a> <br>


    <textarea id="TextToSave" cols="48" id="textarea" rows="5" 

onfocus="if(this.value=='type your text here ...')this.value='';" 

onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='type your text here ...';">type 

your text here ...</textarea>

  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "BHCdJ"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to 

File</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("TextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById

("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>'
```

The problem I have is the links are formatted as `<a href="#" class="button">
<track><location>path 1</location></track></a><br>`
The text copies fine and creates a text file with all of the text in it except it ignores the `</track>` Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean that it ignores the `<track>`? What should happen with it?

Comment: When I click on the link it adds the text of the link to a textarea where it can be sent to a text file. This part is working fine. The text that gets copied should be '<track><location>path1</location></track>' at the moment it copies as '<track><location>path1</location>' It doesn't copy the '</track>' part. It seems to be a problem with the slash in '</track>'

Comment: `<track></track>` is not valid html element it should be just `<track ...>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track

Answer (score 1):

i review your code but can't find anything why it is not work but i made a simple code for you ..hope it will work for you in this case

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
  $('.button').click(function( ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#TextToSave").text() == "type your text here ...") {
      $("#TextToSave").text($(this).html());
    } else {
     $("#TextToSave").text($("#TextToSave").text() + $(this).html()+'</track>');
    }
  });
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: That works great except the first time you click a link it still doesn't copy the '</track>' but every link after that does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be a bug with JQuery's `.html()` method and the `<track>` tag. When I changed `<track>` to `<p>` the code worked fine. Based on the snippet, it doesn't seem like you actually need to use the `<track>` tag, do you?

Comment: Yeah I really do need the `<track>` tags the problem seems to come from the slash in the last element. It doesn't matter what tag I use anything with a slash won't work after `</location>`, but now it's just the first time I click any link the `</track>` won't show up, but the rest do.

Comment: I got it. I had to edit your code a bit. I did this `if ($("#TextToSave").text() == "type your text here ...") {
      $("#TextToSave").text($(this).html()+'</track>');
    } else {
     $("#TextToSave").text($("#TextToSave").text() + $(this).html()+'</track>');
    }` Thank you for your help.